# Using Custom Headers and Transport rules to send emails to junk

Tags: exchange-2016

I have looked for an answer, but I have unfortunately not be able to find something pertaining to my particular scenario.

I have emails that I have already injected a custom header into through another program.

Now that that custom header is in there;

How do I create a transport rule to forward ANY email that has that custom header (unique to suspected spam) to the person's respective junk folder?

Thank you for any help. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Create a transport rule by logging into the ECP (Exchange Control Panel) and going to the Mail Flow section. On the Rules page, create a new rule with the following steps:

1. Type a name for the rule
2. Click 'More options...' to add extra conditions to the rule
3. Set 'Apply this rule if...' to "A message header includes..."
4. Select either "includes any of these words" or "matches these text patterns"
5. Fill in the parameters to match your custom header name and the words or string that you want to match for.

Then decide what you want to do with the messages in the "Do the following..." setting.

- "Set the spam confidence level (SCL) to..." something higher than your Outlook threshold, which is probably around 5 or 6. This may be the easiest method.
- OR "Apply a message classification..." and use your own classification that can be captured in Outlook.
- OR "Prepend the subject of the message with..." a string such as "SPAM: ".

One of these actions, particularly the SCL, should provide Outlook with enough information to automatically mark it as spam and move it to the junk folder.

Comment: Ok, I have a question on your solution (thanks by the way). 

Can I do the first 5 and then just have it go to the junk folder if it matches the custom text pattern in the message header? I have something that is already prepending [Possible Spam] based off the score indicating it is not 100% verified spam. This way we can use the Cisco reporting to mark weather it is spam or not. 

Or is it easier to make the SCL to 100% guarantee outlook makes it go there based off of the SCL being assigned to it based off of the custom header?

Comment: The ECP does not appear to have an action that sends messages directly to the Junk folder. Setting the SCL high could certainly make sure this happens. Other available options include blocking the message entirely, but I don't think that is what you want.